# Is there a way to write to files using js that are on the same server

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to write to a text file on the same server with js. I am reading the file with the fetch function but is there an equivalent to that for writing to files? Because everything I have tried gives a security error.

Comment: You would need to send the data you want written to some server side script that will then write the file. You cannot directly write to a server filesystem from client side.

Comment: You can use `fetch()` with the `PUT` operation. But servers don't usually have this enabled, so you it's done by posting to a server script that writes the file.

Comment: It’s highly likely that any ability to ‘write’ (PUT, POST etc in Http) would require authentication, if indeed the ability is supported.  How you would apply that authentication is an answer as long as a piece of string!